# Can I run 2 Assemblies With Same Methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-s3

AWSSDK now uses individual packages. I am currently using AWSDK v2 but I need some additional features of Amazon Simple Notification Service (Amazon SNS), a new individual package. I don't want to uninstall AWSSDK because there are a whole lot of other methods I use and many many issues it brings up for all my S3 functions.

Can I run both side by side?  When I try to, I get an ambiguous error because both methods are the same name.

If I can how do I refer to the package AWSSDK.SimpleNotificationService and not the old sdk?.

I'm in .net 4.7 using vb if needed.  Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but it's not that easy, you'll need to load the other assembly manually in your code something like this,

In my example I've added the dll in my resources could be that a load from disk is then a bit different.

```
Assembly loadedAssembly = Assembly.Load(<Location to your resource>);
```

Now you have your assembly in memory and you can execute the items in it with reflection calls. I will not go further into reflection here that's a whole other matter.
I don't know if your dll is referencing other dll's in turn, maybe then this solution will not work out.

Comment: Thank you.  I will recode the issues and update to latest.  I appreciate it, you save me alot of research.

Comment: I do hope you have some experience with reflection otherwise this will be a hard issue to tackle.

Comment: Just saw this message again and found the answer a bit silly then I realize that it was my answer.
If you are using AWS with DI you should add it as a service like this for example services.AddAWSService<IAmazonSimpleNotificationService>() you can then register other services as well from AWS along without dll issues. For having access to the AddAWSService you could then use this nuget package AWSSDK.Extensions.NETCore.Setup.
This should have been the answer 2 years ago.